# ic_drawer.png clickable size on tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, navigation-drawer

I have resized my toolbar height, but the `ic_drawer.png` clickable zone don't take all height of the toolbar and vertical center it or put a higher icon size, so how to do this ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#263355"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Look icone is on left top:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default `drawable`s are rendered at their size only. When you resize the toolbar the way you have, the parent layout is resized; its child items may not be. The icon is a child item, (likely to be an `ImageButton`) of the `ToolBar`. You may have to try some custom implementation/override.

Comment: Looks hard to do changes on it

Comment: Agree. Try making something from scratch for it, if you can.